# How to bundle isomorphic commonJS code with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, commonjs, isomorphic-javascript

I have a project that uses nodeJS module format (commonJS) and should also (in parts) run in the browser.

I do have non-isomorphic code paths where I conditionally include modules:

```
var impl;
try {
    // in node, use node-impl
   impl = require('../node-impl');
} catch (err) {
    // running in browser, use browser-impl
    impl = require('../browser-impl');
}
```

Now, I want to use `webpack` to create a bundle that runs in the browser. I therefore need to defined the external (nodeJS specific) modules as `external` in the `webpack.config.js` so that they don't get included in the bundle:

```
external: {
    '../node-impl': true
}
```

I verified that the '../node-impl' code is actually not included in bundle, but the emitted code looks like this:

```
/***/ },
/* 33 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    module.exports = ../node-impl;

/***/ },
```

This is syntactically wrong JS and the browser will throw a syntax error there.

How is this scenario properly handled with webpack.js? Be aware that I do not wish to use webpack for running with nodeJS, only the browser bundles should be created with webpack.

Answer (score 1):

`// Your actual situation:
var impl;
try {
  impl = require('../node-impl');
} catch(e) {
  impl = require('../browser-impl');
}`

You need to refactor this snippet to:

> `var impl = require('../node-impl');`

After this rework, your code is able to work only in a **node js environment**, that's is good because we are going to *mock* this request when bundling for browsers...

`// webpack.browser.config.js
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '../node-impl': '../browser-impl'
    }
  }
};`

[Webpack - Resolve.Alias](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias)
Or using a `package.json#browser`, or https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-packagealias

Comment: But this involves invoking webpack on my nodeJS code - I don't like that. The code runs as it is without any webpack on node and I'd rather not introduce webpack specific code

Comment: While this works for those deps that are available in the browser, still the nodeJS impl will throw a syntax exception as the emitted code in my original question still is in place

Comment: I'll give you another example

Comment: The problem is NOT that for the browser bundle some module is not found. The problem is webpack putting the modules listed in the `externals` section like this: module.exports = ../node-impl - this is invalid JS code and will immediately fail before any code execution.

Comment: I don't understand you, sorry... `externals: {"../node-impl": "window.something"}` must work.

Comment: Because as the name suggest, the "node-impl" contains node-JS specific code that should NOT go into the browser bundle! And therefore it cannot reside on "window.nodeImpl" or anywhere else. I can only make it `externals: { "../node-impl": true }` but then the emmited code is not valid JS code due to the leading dots

Comment: my last update should meet what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the intended purpose of the externals config. Per the docs,

> Specify dependencies that shouldn’t be resolved by webpack, but should become dependencies of the resulting bundle. The kind of the dependency depends on output.libraryTarget.

So you're telling webpack that your build requires that module, but not to bundle it in. It's leaving it out, but attempting to require it.

There are probably a couple of ways to do what you want. Worth mentioning that you can easily have webpack produce multiple builds, with different/shared config, from a single config file, which opens up a lot of possibilities. But the way I'd suggest is to use the [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin) to define a boolean 'constant' that represents the execution context (e.g. `IN_BROWSER = true`). Check that constant in your conditional around the `require()`. Webpack's parser isn't that smart but it can evaluate boolean variables, so it will resolve the conditional correctly and only require the appropriate module. (Using a non-boolean, like `CONTEXT = 'browser'` is too confusing for webpack, and it will parse each require statement.) You can then use the Uglify plugin to remove the 'dead code' in the conditional so it doesn't bloat your production build.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Hitmands I could come up with a solution that is still not perfect, but fits my needs. I introduce a fictious `nonexistingmodule` and declare it as external; I then declare the `node-impl` specific modules to be available as `nonexistingmodule`:

```
externals: {
    'nonexistingmodule': true,
    '../node-impl': 'nonexistingmodule'
}
```

This way I can keep the `try/catch` pattern to load specific implementations and it will still run on node. In the browser the loading of `nonexistingmodule` fails, and the `browser-impl` module is loaded - just as I intended.

I am a big fan of "don't refactor your code to match a tool", so I am going with this solution.